# azure aks deploying to multiple k8s clusters simultaneously with jenkins

Tags: azure, jenkins, kubernetes

## Problem statement

i had created multiple pipelines in my jenkins env which can deploy kubernates objects to multiple cluster. if i execute single job at a time it works well but it might provide unstable output if multiple jobs executed for different environments

### Basic steps for deploying to AKS cluster

- login to azure

```
az login --service-principal -u $AZURE_CLIENT_ID -p $AZURE_CLIENT_SECRET -t $AZURE_TENANT_ID
```

- get credentials

```
az aks get-credentials --resource-group "+resourceGroup+" --name "+clustername+" --overwrite-existing
```

- kubectl apply

```
kubectl apply -f myk8sfiles.yml
```

when i execute single pipeline job it works fine but when i try to execute multiple pipeline jobs i assume my az aks get-credentials and kubectl apply commands will provide unstable output.

How can i execute deployment to multiple AKS clusters in parallel?

Answer (score 2):

just save credentials to a specific place on disk for each cluster and use those specific credentials from the kubectl.

reading: https://kubernetes.io/docs/tasks/access-application-cluster/configure-access-multiple-clusters/